# New ID in QGIS not duplicated

Tags: qgis, arcgis-9.3, unique-id

I work mainly with ArcGIS in backoffice, but use QGIS for some field data maintenance, the challenge is that:

The info worked in office has about 4.5M records, but for maintenance purposes, we create a small project (with a few thousand records) just with the data needed for the area we're focusing during a given week. So then, when there's new info to add to the main database, we have to be careful with the ID's, some will be duplicated.

Is there a way to ensure the new records added out the field respect the full ID list (of the 4.5 records in backoffice)?

Comment: Where is your data stored? Shapefile, personal geodatabase, file geodatabase... And the new data coming from the field, is it existing features with updated attributes or new features? How are you updating your data in the office? It would greatly help if you describe in details the process from office to field and then field to office so the readers understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using UUID'S (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier). You need to define (e.g. shapefiles) your `id` column as "String"...

[image]

...and under Layer Properties|Fields set Edit widget to **UUID Generator**:

[image]

When adding features you can see that the UUID is genarated:

[image]

These UUIDs are unique by human gauge throughout the entire universe and until our sun burns in some far away day many billion years ahead...